# Fragment onHiddenChanged not called

Tags: android, fragment, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, hidden

I recently added Fragments to my applications. For a new application i'll need to get
notified as soon as my fragment is shown. So i can do some calculations as soon as my
fragment is shown again.

My Fragment is used with a TabIndicator and it's only one FragmentClass which is used
a few times.

Here's the normal standard override class:

```
@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Still looking for an answer? onHiddenChanged doesn't get called the first time an fragment is shown. Only when it changes state.

From the documentation:

> Called when the hidden state (as returned by isHidden()) of the fragment has changed. Fragments start out not hidden; this will be called whenever the fragment changes state from that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the method wasn't called ever. So i solved it due the fact that my viewpager has a listener. In this listener i call the onHidden-Changed method. Stupid but yeah, it works now.

Comment: It's never been called.

Answer (score 11):

I had same problem.

I used standart guideline practic work with fragment ([Building a Flexible UI](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)).
I have two fragment (ListItemsFragment and InfoItemFragment).
When used normal screen size, I replace ListItemsFragment at InfoItemFragment and
the method onHiddenChanged doesn't call automatic.

```
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, new InfoItemFragment(), "tag_fr_infoItem");
mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
mFragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I think we must called in hide method FragmentTransaction. For example:

```
    ListItemsFragment  mListItemsFragment;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, new InfoItemFragment(), "tag_fr_infoItem");
    if (mListItemsFragment != null) {
        mFragmentTransaction.hide(mListItemsFragment);
    }
    mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    mFragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And now the method onHiddenChanged work fine. When user click back button mListItemsFragment again show and method onHiddenChanged called automatic.

In documentation said:
*this will be called whenever the fragment changes state from that*

I think we must manual change value then method will be called.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **setUserVisibleHint** method to solve some similar problem. Hope it can help you.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        // Do some your work
    } else {
        // Do your Work
    }
}
```

Comment: This is deprecated!

Comment: What's your SDK version ? Android X ?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 28, minSdkVersion 17 & AndroidX

Answer (score 0):

if you use hide() and show() to hide or show your fragment, Any lifecycle method dont't work.so is setUserVisibleHint() .